# SQL join two tables when exists or ont some records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with SQL query. I need to join documents to users in two ways. If user has document assigned then query should return this set of data, but when user hasn't document assigned then query should return documents, which aren't assigned for anyone.

Comment: You have described the issue you are having. Nobody can help you here because you haven't given us any details about anything. Here is as good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Before asking a question, learn how to ask a question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start:

```
if(exists(select 1 from documents where userID = @userID))
begin

end
else
begin 

end
```